# How to populate a spinner Android from a php page?

Tags: android, spinner, populate

I have to populate a spinner from this php page :
http://sce.jelocalise.fr/mobile/ajax/getdevices.php?email=info@mediacom-i.fr&password=thedevil1
I've read lots of tutorials about Spinners and the way to populate them but I failed to adapt those in my code. Here's what it looks like on an iPhone (I have to adapt an iPhone app into an Android version) : 
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/665348IMG0017.png

I have to display just the "vhc_name" in my spinner and retrieve both "vhc_login" and "vhc_password" to connect the user. I've already done a working connection, I just need to retrieve the good IDs to connect the user. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution :

```
String readFeed = readFeed();

ArrayList<Devices> devices = new ArrayList<Devices>();
ArrayList<String> devicesNames = new ArrayList<String>();

try {

  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readFeed);


  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Devices device = new Devices();
    device.setName(jsonObject.optString("vhc_name"));
    device.setId(jsonObject.optString("vhc_login"));
    devices.add(device);
    devicesNames.add(jsonObject.optString("vhc_name"));

  }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myDevicesSpinner);
mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, devicesNames));

}
```

ReadFeed is a method which downloads from the url the Ids :

```
public String readFeed() {
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String userAuth = Param.getParam("user_Webbsite_Identifier").getValue();
String userPass = Param.getParam("user_Webbsite_password").getValue();

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://sce.jelocalise.fr/mobile/ajax/getdevices.php?email="+userAuth+"&password="+userPass+"");
try {
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
  StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
  int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
  if (statusCode == 200) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      builder.append(line);
    }
  } else {
    Log.e(MyDevices.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
  }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e)
{
}
return builder.toString();
}
```